# Docker ENTRYPOINT bash script is executed over and over again

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, dockerfile

Everything in my docker container initialisation goes well except when I run an ENTRYPOINT script at the end of my `Dockerfile` with

```
# ...
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "./shell_scripts/init.sh"]
```

which consists of

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Init app..."
composer update
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate
```

and when I run `docker-compose up --build` it keeps running the script over and over again....

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.13
    container_name: mysql_8.0.13
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
    networks:
      - app-network


  app_n_php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app_php_7.3-rc-fpm
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./app
        target: /var/www/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app_n_php
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose` file? A reason might be that you've set the container to restart always and it keeps exiting/restarting.

Comment: @tgogos It's done

Comment: @tgogos the script keeps executing still after `docker inspect  'container id'`

Comment: `docker inspect ...` your container and check the `RestartCount` value. If it is increasing, it's because your container keeps exiting and your restart policy starts it again. The solution would then be to change your script in a way that it keeps your container running.